# Access element of float cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I don't understand why I can't get this code to work:

```
cv::Mat M(2, 3, CV_32FC1);
cv::Point2f center(20, 20);
M = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(center, 20, 1.0);
float test;
test = M.at<float>(1, 0);
test = M.at<float>(0, 1);
test = M.at<float>(1, 1);
```

The code fails when accessing the elements with M.at. The following assertion comes up:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)si
ze.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channel
s()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3
) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in unknown function, file C:\OpenCV2.2\include\
opencv2/core/mat.hpp, line 517
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To quote Good Will Hunting, *"It's not your fault!"*

`M` has been overwritten with a `CV_64C1` or a `double` rotation matrix and that's why `M.at<float>(i,j)` fails.

So, don't bother initializing `M` ; `cv::getRotationMatrix` will take care of it and return a `CV_64F` matrix which can (of course) be accessed with `M.at<double>(i,j)`.

Comment: @david: Welcome to SO! Please read the [FAQ on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) if you haven't already.

Comment: Sorry I did the +1 but didn't see the button to accept the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the cv namespace, but I would put a breakpoint at the first call to M.at() and look at the members of M.  One of these members is causing the error:

- dims <= 2
- data == 0
- i0 < size.p[0]
- i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels < size.p[1]*channels()
- ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1() `//sure hope it isn't this one`